# How do I select all text nodes in a document?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a document:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Goodbye!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to iterate over all the text nodes in the document, perform named entity recognition (this  component works on plain text input) and then output the xpath of all elements that pass my recognition algorithm.  My problem is I don't know how to grab all the text elements in the document without discarding their xpath information.  For example,

```
root.xpath("//text()")
```

Just yields a flat array of strings:

```
['\n    ', 'Hello World!', '\n    ', 'Goodbye!', '\n  ']
```

All structural information is lost, so I've got no way of telling where in the document each string was.  Is there a better way?

Here's the full source:

```
import lxml.html
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:
    text_string = fin.read()
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(text_string)
text_elements = root.xpath("//text()")
print text_elements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access parent element using `getparent()`:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> text_string = '''<html>
...   <body>
...     <p>Hello World!</p>
...     <p>Goodbye!</p>
...   </body>
... </html>'''
>>> root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(text_string)
>>> text_elements = root.xpath('//text()')
>>> for t in text_elements:
...     print t.getparent(), type(t), repr(t)
... 
<Element body at 0x193b170> <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> '\n    '
<Element p at 0x193b1d0> <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> 'Hello World!'
<Element p at 0x193b1d0> <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> '\n    '
<Element p at 0x193b290> <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> 'Goodbye!'
<Element p at 0x193b290> <class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> '\n  '
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just a simple string, but it turns out it's not.  Thanks!